# Finding the boundaries of integration when calculating P(X + Y > a) or P(X + Y < b) (Jointly Distributed Continuous Random Variables)

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, definite-integrals

I have a problem on setting the boundaries of integration when I'm trying to find probabilities like $P(X + Y > a)$ or $P(X + Y < b)$.

For example, when I have $f(x,y) = \frac {x} {5}\ +\frac {y} {20}$, $0 < x < 1$ and $1 < y < 5$ , I know the boundaries of the integrals when I'm trying to find $P(X + Y > 3)$ should be $(1,5)$ for $dy$ and $(3-y, 1)$ for $dx$.

However, when I have $f(x,y) = xy$, $0 < x < 1$ and $0 < y < 2$, and the question is asking for $P(X + Y < 1)$, I need to change the boundaries of integrals of $dy$ to $(0, 1)$ if I am setting the  boundaries of integration of the $dx$ part to be $(0, 1-y)$. Why does that happen? Why do I get a wrong answer if I leave the dy's boundaries as $(0, 2)$ but I still get the right answer when I leave it as $(1,5)$ for the queston above?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second example, you can't integrate $y$ over $(0,2)$, because we want $X+Y<1$, and since $X\geq 0$, we must have $Y\leq 1$. Thus, $1$ is an upper bound for $Y$. You *could* also integrate $Y$ over $\mathbb R$ and $x$ over $(-\infty, 1-Y)$, but then you should use that $f(x,y)=0$ when $$(x,y)\not\in\{(a,b)|0\leq a\leq 1, \leq b\leq 2\}$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, why can I integrate y over (1, 5) for the first example then? I mean if X + Y has to be greater than 3 and if y = 1, x needs to be 2 but that contradicts the condition of 0 < x < 1.

Comment: There, y should be at least 2, or you should use that p(x=2)=0

Comment: but the solution key disagrees with that new answer obtained from integrating y over (2,5) :(

Comment: Even if I change the upper bound to 3 and make the boundaries (2,3), I still cannot get the answer shown in the answer key (which is 11/15).

Comment: You shouldn't  change the upper bound, because you want x+y to be at least 3, so y may be 5

Comment: still, I get $\frac{9}{10}$ for integrating above (2, 5), not 11/15.

Comment: actually should I always place the variable with wider boundaries in the inner integral to avoid such problem? Like $\int _0^1\left(\int _{3-x}^5\left(\frac{x}{5}+\frac{y}{20}\right)dy\right)dx$ for the first question and $\int _0^1\left(\int _0^{1-x}xydy\right)dx$ for the second question?

Comment: That seems right to me.